# Netbeans shows two icons on Launcher

Tags: unity, netbeans

I use netbeans in Ubuntu Natty. I have added it in the launcher and it works. But there is an issue. When I start netbeans it shows two Icons. One is for the launcher and the other for the active netbeans (the latter's icon is with little white triangle). Is there a workaround?

Comment: Might be related to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/754334

Comment: Exactly, I wonder when it will be fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it is a bug in unity described here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/751909
I will keep an eye on the ticket and see if it is fixed. If they wont fix it until october, I will upgrade to Oneiric

Comment: I upgraded to Precise and I don't use NB IDE Much. I use my company's IDE

Answer (score 5):

[Offline] There is a netbeans plugin that works around this problem: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40321/unity-launcher
[/Offline]

[Update]

Or just add `StartupWMClass=Apache NetBeans IDE` to your netbeans.desktop starter in ~/.local/share/applications/ or /usr/share/applications/

[/Update]

Comment: I upvoted your answer, I will check for that!

Comment: That link is dead

Comment: @AntonDuzenko Just add 'StartupWMClass=Apache NetBeans IDE' to your netbeans.desktop starter in .local/share/applications

Answer (score 2):

As [Curious Apprentice](https://askubuntu.com/users/53649/curious-apprentice) mentions, go to `/usr/share/applications` and edit the .desktop file which corresponds to your NetBeans installation. In my case, this file was named `netbeans-6.8.desktop`

Add the following two lines to the end of the file (in my case, after `Terminal=0`)

```
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=java-lang-Thread
```

Comment: When installing with the netbeans installer, you will find the netbeans.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications/

Answer (score 1):

open up `gksudo /usr/share/applications`
and delete one of the netbeans.desktop